# syntax if else inside function

Tags: c

I have simple else if and have errors on the word syntax - for.
Please help me to fix this

```
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'   
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

My code is checking which array is bigger and puts the bigger.
Thats my all fnction:

```
void PrintIdentical(...)
{
    int i;
    int smaller;


     ...

    for (i = 0; i < smaller; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d", arrA[i]);
       printf ("%d", arrB[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you properly closing the body of the function definition? Perhaps you are, but but you haven't posted the entire function definition, so wondering in case you missed that.

Comment: The code above is not complete.

Comment: Could you post some of the code surrounding `enticl()`?

Comment: Oh... it looked better the first time.

Comment: @Alexxx - You really shouldn't remove the error from the question. That makes it really hard for those coming here later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; ...
```

This syntax is C99, it is not allowed in previous standards. Since you've already declared `i`, you can just change that to:

```
for (i = 0; ...
```

If you want a block-level `i` in there anyway (it will shadow the `i` that you defined earlier in your function), then use:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...
```

or get a compiler that supports C99.

Answer (score 1):

This code should compile, unless you actually forgot to close your function with a trailing `}`.

One other issue could be the redeclaration of `i`. I've seen this on some compilers. Also, a note - in the for loop you don't need to redeclare `i`, you can use the existing declaration.

I'm also assuming you defined the function `print` yourself.

Comment: All compilers I've worked with can handle a declaration of a variable inside a block with the same name like that. However, some debuggers can't, so maybe that threw you off?

Comment: It doesn't throw me off, compiling with gcc (can't remember the version) under solaris definetely gives the error.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over what "declaring a variable in a for loop" means. Sorry. I meant if you have `int i; for (...) {int i;}` that should always be correct. However with `for (int i = ...)` compilers don't all agree with the specs and then the problems start.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly using C, you can't declare variables inside the `For loop` body as you are doing now. I have tried this using GCC and i got compile error.

```
error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
```

Also, you seem to be re-declaring `i`, and some compilers won't able to detect that as a new scope.

Comment: So it depends on whether this is C99 or not. Also, I don't know a single compiler that can't handle redefinitions like that. It's in the specs!

Comment: @MrLister: I tried to compile it on http://codepad.org, selecting C, and I got that error. As for redefinition, I recall that VC++ 6.0, complained if we re-declared a variable inside a for loop. It has been a long time though, since I used VC++ 6.0.

Comment: VC++6 complains if you declare a variable *after* it's declared in a `for` clause. VC++6 used the 'pre-standard style' scoping for variables declared in the `for` clause - that is, the variable remained 'alive' after the end of the `for` loop. So you couldn't have another definition of the variable name after the `for` loop.  Just for completeness, VC6 (compiling C code) didn't permit variable declarations in a `for` clause (or after the first non-declaration statement in a block). Unfortunately, that's still the case for MSVC when compiling C code.

Answer (score 0):

```
void enticl(int arrA[], int arrA_size, int arrB[], int arrB_size)
{
    int i;
    int smaller;
    int *arr;

    if(arrA_size>arrB_size)
    {
        smaller=arrB_size;
        arr = arrB;
    }
    else
    {
        smaller=arrA_size;
        arr = arrB;

    }

    for(i = 0; i < smaller; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```